# Forcing the compiler to provide default constructor in C++

Tags: c++, constructor

I have written a C++ program without defining any constructor. Following is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class test
{
    public:

        void print()
        {
            cout<< "Inside Print"<<endl;
        }
};
int main()
{
   test t;
   t.print();
   return 0;
}
```

When I deassembled the code, I did not find any occurrence of calling the default constructor. Following is the assembly code snippet of the main function:

```
8 main:
      9 .LFB1516:
     10         pushl   %ebp
     11 .LCFI0:
     12         movl    %esp, %ebp
     13 .LCFI1:
     14         subl    $8, %esp
     15 .LCFI2:
     16         andl    $-16, %esp
     17         movl    $0, %eax
     18         subl    %eax, %esp
     19         leal    -1(%ebp), %eax
     20         movl    %eax, (%esp)
     21         call    _ZN4test5printEv
     22         movl    $0, %eax
     23         leave
     24         ret
```

As you can see, there is only one `call` instruction in the above snippet (line # 21). It is calling the `print()` function. Now I modified my code slightly and introduced a `constructor`. Following is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class test
{
    public:
        test()
        {
        }
        void print()
        {
            cout<< "Inside Print"<<endl;
        }
};
int main()
{
    test t;
    t.print();
    return 0;
}
```

I deassembled the code again and found the following:

```
 8 main:
      9 .LFB1519:
     10         pushl   %ebp
     11 .LCFI0:
     12         movl    %esp, %ebp
     13 .LCFI1:
     14         subl    $8, %esp
     15 .LCFI2:
     16         andl    $-16, %esp
     17         movl    $0, %eax
     18         subl    %eax, %esp
     19         leal    -1(%ebp), %eax
     20         movl    %eax, (%esp)
     21         call    _ZN4testC1Ev
     22         leal    -1(%ebp), %eax
     23         movl    %eax, (%esp)
     24         call    _ZN4test5printEv
     25         movl    $0, %eax
     26         leave
     27         ret
```

As you can see, it called the constructor in line #21.
Now my question is, if I do not define any constructor in my code,doesn't the compiler provide a default constructor in all the cases? If it doesn't, then in what situations or rather how can I force the compiler to provide a default constructor for me???

Sorry for the lengthy question :P

Comment: The constructor is not created because it is not needed. There is nothing to construct.

Comment: But when I create an object, the constructor should get called, right???

Comment: Try to turn off all optimizations.

Answer (score 13):

The program *behaves* as it should. Machine code generation is not part of the standard, and you have no right to expect *any* particular machine code output — you're only guaranteed that the output program does what you told it to.

Comment: For example, `static_cast<volatile void>(0);` is a valid expression that probably doesn't create any machine code; yet it is a perfectly sensible C++ statement.

Answer (score 6):

Why would you want to force your compiler to bloat your binary and to slowdown your program?

Good compiler will call default constructor (**or any other function**) only if that makes sense - if calling it will make any effects.

Optimization will just exclude default constructor (which will do nothing) call from the program.

Answer (score 1):

> if I do not define any constructor in my code,doesn't the compiler provide a default constructor in all the cases

No, only if you don't define any other constructors. If your class has any user-declared constructor then that suppresses the implicit declaration of a default constructor.

Even if you don't define other constructors, unless the default constructor actually has to *do* something, e.g. call a non-trivial constructor of a base class or member variable, then it will be trivial and so will do nothing, and so no code needs to be generated. Only a stupid compiler would generate a completely empty function and insist on calling it just to do nothing.

> If it doesn't, then in what situations or rather how can I force the compiler to provide a default constructor for me???

If you want to ensure it exists then define it, but if it does nothing then it's a waste of time.  If it needs to do something such as construct base classes or member variables (and it isn't suppressed by another user-declared constructor) then it will be created by the compiler.

The compiler is doing the right thing, you don't need to force it to do anything.